# How do I get delivery slots between the times of 2pm and 5pm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, postgresql-9.3

I have a model called `DeliverySlot`. Its attributes look like:

```
#<DeliverySlot:0x007f955a322cf0> {
  :id => 2562,
  :from => Sat, 31 Dec 2016 12:00:00 UTC +00:00
}
```

`from` is a `datetime` column. Delivery slots are an hour and 30 minutes apart from each other.

How can I get all delivery slots from Monday-Friday that are between the hour of 2pm (14:00) and 5pm (17:00)?
As of now I have:

Assuming, `Time.now.utc.strftime('%A')` is `Monday`.

```
DeliverySlot.where(from: (Time.now.utc..(Time.now.utc + 5.days).end_of_day))
```

I am using Postgres btw. Should I be using Postgres date functions? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 2):

I know I am bit late and you probably got this down pat by now.

I created a method called slots and it takes 2 parameters they are dates.

```
  ...
   # Model.slot(Date.today, Date.today+7.days)
  def self.slot(start_date, end_date)
    start_date.upto(end_date) do |date|
      if ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday'].include?(date.strftime('%A'))
        (date.beginning_of_day.to_i .. date.end_of_day.to_i).step(30.minutes).each do |time|
          if Time.at( time ).strftime('%R') > '13:00' && Time.at( time ).strftime('%R') < '17:00'
            puts "Create Slot Date: #{date.strftime('%D')} Time: #{Time.at( time )}"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I hope that this helps